# package node-webkit app for windows - showing blank screen when run

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

[image]I developed an app with node-webkit 0.12.3. I now want to package it to have a single executable, if possible, to distribute. For now, i didn't even manage to generate a working .nw app.
I tried following the guide at https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/How-to-package-and-distribute-your-apps with step 2b. I generated the .nw package merged it with nw.exe into an exe, and put all the necessary dlls and pak in the same directory. Before proceeding to generate the distributable exe, i tested it to see if it works, but instead of loading my html file and my app, i get a blank screen with a NW dark grey background, with nw:blank in the toolbar.

here's the structure of my app

```
|____node_modules  
|  
|____package.json  
|     
|  
|____app  
   |  
   |  
   |____ index.html  
   |____ scripts  
        |_____ app.js  
        |_____ actions.js  
        |_____ parser.js  
        |_____ loggingstore.js  
   |____ images  
           |__ icon.png  
   |____ css  
        |__ main.css
```

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "morningops",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Morning Ops Automation",
  "keywords": [],
  "window": {
    "icon": "app/images/icon.png",
    "toolbar": true,
    "frame": true,
    "width": 800,
    "height": 600,
    "position": "center",
    "resizable": true
  },
  "webkit": {
    "plugin": false
  },
  "main": "app/index.html",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^0.13.3",
    "require-text": "0.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "^11.1.0",
    "chai": "^3.2.0",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-nw-builder": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
    "mocha": "^2.0.1",
    "nw-builder": "^2.0.2",
    "reactify": "^1.1.1",
    "watchify": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "watchify app/scripts/app.js -o app/bundle.js -v",
    "test": "mocha",
    "app": "nw .",
    "build": "./build/build",
    "clean": "rm -rf build/cache app/bundle.js"
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      [
        "reactify",
        {
          "es6": true
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like you might have missed a step here or there. You didn't get an app working before packaging it, so that tells me there's a problem with your configuration. What does your package.json look like? Please give us more information that we can assist you.

Comment: It did work! running nw . inside the app folder started it and it worked. what i meant was that it did not work *after* i packaged nw.exe and the .nw zip into a single executable. Running that executable started the app with a blank screen. I updated the original post with my app structure and package.json

Comment: bump. even packaged nw examples, like explorer don't work

Comment: I've not been able to reproduce this behaviour yet, I will have to try on a different machine with a fresh install. Can you open the developer console at all to see if there are any messages?

Comment: Nothing in the console.... i am attaching a screenshot of the resulting window to the original post.

Comment: Really weird - what flavour of Windows are you running, if I may ask?

Comment: I am running Windows 7, 64 bits

Comment: OK, for that I have to wait until I get home, then I can try it out on a similar machine and see what happens.

Comment: ok. rewrote the code for the electron platform. i did not want to waste more time on this but it would still be cool to see if we can make it work. haven't managed so far...